# Referenciar Factory no Controller do Angular

Tags: angularjs

Bom noite, como faço para instanciar a Factory no Controller? estou com o seguinte erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
var app = angular.module('App', []);
app.controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope, $http, LoginFactory) {...
```

Tenho o código acima

Comment: Olá, você poderia postar o código da `factory` também?

Comment: Consegui resolver amigo, mesmo assim obrigado :D

Comment: Brayan, poste a solução se julgar necessário! :D